# Dart/Polymer not wiring up using HtmlImport but working perfect with dart2j

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

As you know 0.16.0 has brought some changes. For me personally I was doing an `initPolymer`, then carry on with a Future using `.onReady`. Then I would structure the rest of my application around having a html file for a component which imported what ever was needed and then a `<script>` tag pointing to the .dart file with the `@CustomTag` and the class for the component.

This was the pattern I was using no matter how complex or lightweight the component. Since 0.16.0 I have move some of the more lighter weight stuff over using @CustomElement element and have been using @HtmlImports to bring my dart and HTML declarations together. This has all worked well, it is an improvement and the way forward.

Here comes the But... I have have a bootstrap problem. (Repo with a strip down example here https://github.com/rayk/weirdImports)

I believe the way I have set the imports in the above example is the new "preferred practice". But it does not work when I run it under the DartVM. All is well when I $dart2js it.

Could someone have a look at this and also comment on what would be best practice today on some of this early lifecycle bootstrap stuff.

My ideal world would to have a index.html that look something like.

```dart
<html>
...
....


<body unresolved fullbleed>
<my-app></my-app>

<script type='application/dart src=index.dart>
```

Then in my index.dart file

```dart
main(){
  initPolymer().then((z) {

      setupLogging();

      doOtherEnvironmentStuff();

      kickAFewBeaconsEtc();

  });
```

I know the above looks like the old way, but I am looking just to do it for boot-up. The MyApp class and all it's descending components  would adopt the `@HtmlImport` approach which keeps the declarative `<polymer-element>` HTML ultra clean and a second class citizen to the dart class. Where the element was simple and required no real backing code or features I then `@CustomElement` the whole thing.

If this approach is not too crazy... could someone have a look a the attached public repo and show me what I am missing... I am crazy looking at it because I can not see what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.........

**EDIT**

I think the problem could related to Version 39.0.2171.99 of Chromium. I have been using the a command line flag `--no-sandbox`, I remove that and it appears to be working...

Comment: I tried your example from the GitHub repo and it shows "Hello from app-main component" in Dartium. What do you get, what result do you expect instead.

Comment: Works for me too, and you are doing it right :)

Comment: Thanks for looking guys... as you can see from the edit I have tracked it down. Nothing to do with our Dart/Dartium or polymer. All user (me) environment. I had a Symlink to version Version 37.0.2062.76 (289648) of Dartium. Once I blow that away all was good. Thanks again for checking.

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer and then accept it (only allowed after two days I AFAIR) so the question doesn't stay open as unanswered.